# In Android Studio, what does Window.setFlag(int flag, int mask) do?

Tags: android-studio

The documentation states: "set the flags of the window, as per the **`WindowManager.LayoutParams`** flags." The description doesn't help me much, though. What is a `window flag`? Can someone clarify the parameters?

Answer (score 1):

SetFlags(int flag, int mask) set behaviorial options of a window
The `int` parameters specify the bits of the window flags field. 
The first parameter `flags`  specifies the new window flags.
The second parameter `mask` indicates which of the window `flag bits` to modify (remaining bits will remain as it is).

Comment: Can you explain what "window flag bits" essentially mean ?